# Issue in jquery scrolling page to top of the page in update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using update panel in aspx page and I want that whenever page is partially loaded, the page should get scrolled on the top of page.
I have written jquery as

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    // re-bind your jQuery events here
    this.window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    alert("helloo");
});
```

The above jquery is not working!!! Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your script is included outside of the `UpdatePanel` content. Include the script within the update panel.

Additionally, consider changing the command to perform the scrolling to:

```
 $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
 $("html, body").scrollLeft(0);
```